# How to run graphDB cluster in syncronious mode

Tags: graphdb

How to fix problem with replication lag in graphDB? Rarelycluster returns old value after update under load, this happens as graphBD cluster works in asyncronious mode (value from out-to-dated slave is returned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should turn local consistency on.

There are three types of **local consistency** in cluster and they are passed as header value:

**None** - header "X-GraphDB-Local-Consistency", header value "none", e.q the query will be sent to any readable worker (default)

**Last committed** - header "X-GraphDB-Local-Consistency", header value "last-committed", e.q the query will be sent to a worker, that has processed the latest transaction

**Updating** - header "X-GraphDB-Local-Consistency", header value "updating", e.q same as last committed, but in addition, if the cluster is executing an update, the query will be sent to the worker that is processing the test transaction